# R shift scale at x axis date with a non-continuous sequence of time

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have a time serie data from two consecutive years (2017-2018), from january to december of each year. Then I need to plot the data from sept-17 to april-18.

I could do it with a very hand-made code, however I realize it could be done very much straightforward way with the packages availabe today for managing dates on plots (packages "scales", "lubridate", etc.)

Can someone help me to simplify my work for doing the second plot?
I will really appreciate it.

```r
  suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library("tidyverse", quietly = T)))


  dat <- tibble(
    date = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by=1),
    var = rgamma(length(date), shape=2, scale=2)) %>% 
    mutate(year = lubridate::year(date),
           month = lubridate::month(date), 
           julian = lubridate::yday(date))
  dat
#> # A tibble: 730 x 5
#>    date         var  year month julian
#>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 2017-01-01 12.9   2017     1      1
#>  2 2017-01-02  6.69  2017     1      2
#>  3 2017-01-03  6.11  2017     1      3
#>  4 2017-01-04  1.68  2017     1      4
#>  5 2017-01-05  1.22  2017     1      5
#>  6 2017-01-06 10.2   2017     1      6
#>  7 2017-01-07  5.13  2017     1      7
#>  8 2017-01-08  4.61  2017     1      8
#>  9 2017-01-09  3.79  2017     1      9
#> 10 2017-01-10  1.11  2017     1     10
#> # … with 720 more rows

  dat %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(julian, var, color = factor(month), linetype=factor(year)))
```

[image]

```r
  dat %>%
    filter((year == 2017 & month %in% c("9","10", "11", "12"))|
             (year == 2018 & month %in% c("1", "2", "3"))) %>%
    mutate(julian_AWS = ifelse(julian>=244, julian-243, julian+123)) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(julian_AWS, var, color = factor(month), linetype=factor(year)))+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,#S
                                  31,#O
                                  61,#N
                                  91,#D
                                  121,#E
                                  151,#F
                                  181),#M
                       labels = c("Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"))+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(hjust=-1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to delve into the julian date formats. See if this gets you what you need:

```
dat %>%
filter(date >= '2017-09-01', date < '2018-04-01') %>% 
ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(date, var, color = factor(month), linetype = factor(year))) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = -1))
```

[image]

For more info on date label formats, see `?strftime`

Comment: Yes, you're right, now I think I did not ask the correct question. Because I want to use it also for overlapping the 2017-2018 daily temp_mean over a 40 years time serie of temp_mean. Then I would not be able to filter the data by this way for the average time serie data. Maybe I will ask a new question.

Comment: I would really appreciate you could take a look at this new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55994667/shift-scale-at-date-x-axis-with-a-non-continuous-sequence-of-time-in-r