# Shift scale at date x-axis with a non-continuous sequence of time in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have a time serie data from 2000-2018, from january to december of each year. I want to overlap the lines of the average values of temp_mean for the period 2000-2016 and the observed temp_mean of 2017-2018.

I could do it with a very hand-made code, however I realize it could be done very much straightforward way with the packages availabe today for managing dates on plots (packages "scales", "lubridate", etc.)

Can someone help me to simplify my work for doing the resulting plot? I will really appreciate it.

```r
suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library("tidyverse", quietly = T)))

dat <- tibble(
  date = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by=1),
  tmean = rgamma(length(date), shape=2, scale=2)) %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(date),
         month = lubridate::month(date),
         julian = lubridate::yday(date))

# calculate daily average temperature for the serie 2010-2016
dat_serie <- dat %>%
  filter(year<2017) %>%
  group_by(julian) %>%
  summarise(
    month = first(month),
    avg = mean(tmean, .2, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ungroup()


p0 <- dat_serie %>%
  filter(month %in% c("1", "2", "3", "9","10", "11", "12")) %>%
  mutate(julian_AWS = ifelse(julian>=244, julian-243, julian+123)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(julian_AWS, avg, color = factor(month)))+

  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,#S
                                31,#O
                                61,#N
                                91,#D
                                121,#E
                                151,#F
                                181),#M
                     labels = c("Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(hjust=-1))
```

My main concern is how to match both, the serie and 2017-2018, x-axis values for overlapping the y-values. With some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993404/r-shift-scale-at-x-axis-date-with-a-non-continuous-sequence-of-time/55994045#55994045) I added the 2017-2018 line:

```r
dat_17_18 <-  dat %>% 
filter(date >= '2017-09-01', date < '2018-03-30') %>% 
mutate(julian_AWS = ifelse(julian>=244, julian-243, julian+123)) 

p0 + geom_line(data = dat_17_18,
            aes(julian_AWS, tmean, linetype = factor(year)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. If I understand correctly, you can join your aggregated data to your 2017-2018 data and continue using the dates from your original dataset

```
dat_17_18 <-
  dat %>%
  filter(date >= '2017-09-01', date < '2018-03-30') %>%
  left_join(dat_serie, by = c("juian", "month"))

ggplot(dat_17_18, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = avg, color = factor(month))) +
  geom_line(aes(y = tmean, linetype = factor(year))) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = -1))
```

Also, since we're in the guts of this chart, having the base be an area chart might be easier to read rather than 2 jagged lines.
[image]

```
ggplot(dat_17_18, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_area(
    aes(y = avg, fill = factor(month)), 
    show.legend = FALSE, alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = tmean, linetype = factor(year))) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = -1))
```

Comment: Do you know how to drop "april" from x-axis?

Comment: You can use `scale_x_date(..., expand = expand_scale(0, 0))`

Comment: You did my day!